# How to create a fresh Highcharts instance?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I use `Highcharts.setOptions(...);` to set some global configuration like the theme for my old app. We are doing an overhaul and the newer version has design differences. I want to do the theming at the global level as I did for the old graphs. The problem is applying one set of config at global levels becomes shared by both the instance.

So I was wondering if there is a way to create a new fresh instance of Highcharts and then use that on the dashboard. Something like axios.

```
const instance = axios.create({})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could not understant how your global file is configured.
BUt just to create new instance you can use the syntax

var newChart= new Chart({chart: { renderTo: 'container' }) ;

Just add one more instance in your global file and use it in other parts

Answer (score 0):

You should use `setOptions` only once, because it overwrites global settings.

The experimental workaround is to store current `Highcharts` instance to variable and load Highcharts again:

HTML:

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script>
    var Highcharts1 = Highcharts;
    Highcharts = null;
</script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

JS:

```
Highcharts1.setOptions({
    chart: {
        ...
    }
});

var chart1 = Highcharts1.chart({
    ...
});

var chart2 = Highcharts.chart({
    ...
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/38zLxghc/

Related thread: [Highcharts: setOptions for two different series of charts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20645341/highcharts-setoptions-for-two-different-series-of-charts)